# Technical analysis of rhythm in Sofi Needs a Ladder

Tags: polyrhythm

I apologize for the subject of my rhythm analysis--many of you are likely to turn your noses up, but... Deadmou5 has a song "Sofi Needs A Ladder" and I'm trying to understand the rhythmic elements going on here.

The song starts with a high synth rhythm.  It starts all mashed together, but by 0:30 resolves into a crisp, defined pattern.  At the same point in time that the synth has resolved, a snare (electronic) is introduced playing in a different rhythm. I believe this is a 2:3 polyrhythm with the high synth the 3 and the snare the 2.

Much of the rest of the song is a simple kick/snare pattern; nothing exciting going on there.

Starting at about 2:45, that 2:3 polyrhythm seems to start to sneak back in with different pitches of that high synth.

The part I'm trying to make sense of is the part from about 3:30 to 4:00 in the song.  Here we have that same 2:3 rhythm that we had at the beginning of the song, but there is also a low synth that is added (I think) as a half count to every high synth hit.  How would you count that?

My understanding is that 2:3 is counted with triplets, so (**bold** is 2, `inverse` is 3)

**`1`** - trip- `let` - **2** - `trip` - let

If I'm right about the high and low synth, we should basically have 2:6, but the 6 alternates between high and low (**bold** is 2, `inverse` is 3, <s>strikethrough</s> is the inverted 3)

**`1`**-&-<s>trip</s>-a-`let`-o-**<s>2</s>**-&-`trip`-a-<s>let</s>-o

But when I listen to it, it doesn't seem to line up that nicely.  Am I hearing it wrong? Am I counting it wrong?  How does this section work?

(As you answer the question, please explain it to me like I'm 10 because I only know a little bit when it comes to musical theory, counting, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I hear is not a 2 over 3, but a 4 over 3 pattern going on.

I transcribed what I hear and explain it progressively so it is clear. I used chrome song maker to make the graphics. You can go there and draw the same beats so you can listen to it yourself: https://musiclab.chromeexperiments.com/Song-Maker/

The snare is placed on every downbeat, so we got 4 snares per bar. (Red box = Snare)

[image]

The high synth starts with the 4:3 (4 synths for 3 snares)
Blue/Purple is the synth, Im putting it there for 3 snare hits, 4 synth hits:

[image]

The the low synth appears at 3:34. The low synth also does a 4:3, exactly as the high synth (4 low synth for each 3 snare hits), but it is starting at another beat as the high synth, so they are displaced. For a bit they are synchronized, one hitting just before the other. (Low synth in green)

[image]

Then the high synth starts gradually speeding up and extending the sound so it doesn't have such a defined attack, going outside the grid, giving this 'drunk' feel to the whole thing. Eventually it returns to the groove.